# About styling Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, customization

For my custom dialog I use `parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`. Sourse code of [Theme.Holo.Dialog](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/themes.xml)(API 11)

```
<style name="Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@android:style/DialogWindowTitle.Holo</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:drawable/dialog_full_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Holo.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">@bool/config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside</item>

    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>

    <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@android:style/Holo.ButtonBar.AlertDialog</item>
    <item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless.Small</item>

    <item name="textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceInverse">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Inverse</item>

    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingLeft">16dip</item>
    <item name="listPreferredItemPaddingRight">16dip</item>
</style>
```

How to set `<item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>` in android 2.2(API 8)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this in code since API v1 using [setCanceledOnTouchOutside()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside%28boolean%29).